# Extraxt different csv files from one csv based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hi i'm a python beginner. 
I would like to extract different csv files from one big csv based on a value within a column. 
My csv looks like this:

```
IDMember    Risk    Area
1             2       30
2             1       20
3             2       10
```

I have thousands of value with the same `IDMember` and i would like to extract one csv for each one of this ID, with the ID within the csv filename. 
How can i do it?

i'm trying something like this, but i think i'm missing something:

```
import os
import pandas

df = r'MyCSVPath'
outFolder = r'MyOutputFolder'

col = 'MemberID'

for col in df.groupby('MemberID'):
    df.to_csv(f'{MemberID}.csv')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: `for i in df['MemberID'].unique(): df[df['MemberID'].eq(i)].to_csv(....)`

Comment: @DaemonPainter: I do not think that this one really addresses OP's question. `groupby` is probably more on topic...

Comment: There are different problems here: 1/ open a csv file and read a csv file into a pandas DataFrame: `open` and `read_csv` 2/ split a csv according to values in one column: `groupby` and iterating on a GroupBy 3/ open a new file inside a folder: `os.path` and again `open` 4/ save a dataframe to a csv file `to_csv`. Maybe you should try to focus one question at a time... I think that reading [ask] could be useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are having the dataframe where id's are duplicated.

```
   IDMember  Risk  Area
0         1     2    30
1         2     1    20
2         3     2    10
3         4     2    15
4         1     2    45
5         2     2    40
6         4     3    50
7         1     3    30
```

script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csvFile.csv') #reading the csv file

df1 = df['IDMember'].drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=False) #creating dataframe showing unique ids

for elem in df1:  #iterating through each id
  df2 = df.loc[df['IDMember'] == elem]
  print(df2)
  df2.to_csv('IDmember'+str(elem)+'.csv')  #writing to separate csv by each id
```

Comment: Thanks, actually is creating all the csv files i need, but they are all the same, only the filename is different.

Comment: I changed the last row with `df1` instead of `df`, and the content of files is different as i wanted, but there is only the column related to `IDMember`

Comment: I am sorry, I have mistakingly put print() there. I have edited the post - now it should work.

Comment: It was not working, it was just giving me empty csv with headers. I Changed the last two rows , with `df1 =`... and `df1.to_csv =`...

Comment: I have changed name of the dataframe df to df2 - the problem was that df was changed after first iteration and csv files were empty. Hope now it will finally work.